# elasticsearch: boost query based on values of a variable

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand how to boost query in elasticsearch depending on absolute value of a variable. For example

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": [
            { "match": {"field1": {"query": 10, "boost": 2}} }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to make sure the field1 influences the score but I dont know any absolute value. For example, document will field1 = 20 will get higher score as compared to document with field1 = 10. However, this is different from sort. Because sorting is absolute. I just want this variable to contribute to the overall score but this is not the only field controlling the overall score.

Comment: Check function_score query

Comment: Thanks Vineet! From there I found field_value_factor. It seems that might solve my problem

Comment: with multi_match query you can try different fields with different boost filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here would be [function_score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)
It can be seen as the swiss army knife for customizing scores. 
You can use field_value_factor function in it to achieve what you are looking for.